# How to calculate the week number within a month, given Sun-Sat is the week

Tags: math, logic, date-arithmetic

Let's say that my week starts on Sunday and ends on Saturday.

Given a date, I want to find it's week number in that month but also consider partial weeks into account. For ex., in this calendar, http://cityofdefiance.com/wp-content/uploads/2019-calendar-3-e1545926721248.jpg

01-Jan-19: Week 1
06-Jan-19: Week 2
26-Jan-19: Week 4
28-Jan-19: Week 5

01-Feb-19: Week 1
28-Feb-19: Week 5

01-Jun-19: Week 1
30-Jun-19: Week 6

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

```
Month1stSunday = 8-Date.DayOfWeek(Date.StartOfMonth([FieldDate]), Day.Sunday)

if (Date.Day([FieldDate]) <= [Month1stSunday]) then "W1" 
  else if (Date.Day([FieldDate]) <= [Month1stSunday]+7) then "W2" 
  else if (Date.Day([FieldDate]) <= [Month1stSunday]+14) then "W3" 
  else if (Date.Day([FieldDate]) <= [Month1stSunday]+21) then "W4" 
  else if (Date.Day([FieldDate]) > [Month1stSunday]+21) then "W5" 
else ""
```

May not be great but works fine.